# How to display tokens on a page in D7

Tags: tokens

Drupal 7 built tokens into core. Is there a way to display tokens on a page without modifying a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) does the trick. After the module is enabled, you can edit or create create a text format that replaces tokens with text: admin/config/content/formats